# What's a good way to disable double buffering in the current java

Tags: java, double-buffering

I just need a way to turn off double buffering in java the current way doesn't seem to work.

I've tried using the RepaintManager and its setDoubleBufferingEnabled method and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Turn off double buffering for everything, or just one component?  The latter can be done with the [setDoubleBuffered](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDoubleBuffered%28boolean%29) method.

Comment: I guess it would just be one component, I'm not sure I'm asking for a professor of mine who's having trouble turning off double buffering and I thought the problem was interesting. I don't have his code on me so I'll have to take a look tomorrow.